# Create an efficient ImmutableMap collector that holds an ImmutableList for each key

Tags: java, stream, guava, immutability, collectors

I've been musing on this for a week and I'm not quite sure of a way to do this. A common task I am running into is building an ImmutableMap containing ImmutableLists, as in `ImmutableMap<K,ImmutableList<V>>`, for the values of the given type, and I'd like to do it through a collector so I can leverage it on streams.

I found this great ImmutableMap collector on a blog shown below. But I want the V to be an ImmutableList, and I'd like the incoming stream to map multiple values with the same key paired to said key with an ImmutableList value. Every implementation I've tried has been suboptimal and not stream-like, as I kept falling back on using a plain HashMap holding ImmutableList.Builder values, and when I'm done populating I would loop through it and convert it into ImmutableList values by calling build() and putting it in a new map. Any ideas?

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K, V>>
    toImmutableMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {

    Supplier<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>> supplier =
        ImmutableMap.Builder::new;

    BiConsumer<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>, T> accumulator =
         (b, t) -> b.put(keyMapper.apply(t), valueMapper.apply(t));

    BinaryOperator<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>> combiner =
         (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build());

    Function<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>, ImmutableMap<K, V>> finisher =
       ImmutableMap.Builder::build;

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```

I'd like the implementation to have a header of...

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K, ImmutableList<V>>>
```

Okay I was successful thanks to fge's help! See answer below.

Comment: Wait, you are using Guava, so why don't you use `Multimap`s? There are also immutable versions of them

Comment: huh, forgot about this guy... and the immutable version of it. Let me play with this and see if I can make it a collector...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I successfully leveraged ImmutableListMultimap to accomplish this! Thanks fge!

If anybody sees anything that can be improved (I think the combiner cannot be optimized but correct me if I'm wrong), please let me know.

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableListMultimap<K, V>> toImmutableListMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {

    Supplier<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>> supplier = ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::new;

    BiConsumer<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>, T> accumulator = (b, t) -> b
            .put(keyMapper.apply(t), valueMapper.apply(t));

    BinaryOperator<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>> combiner = (l, r) -> { 
        final ImmutableListMultimap<K, V> rightMap = r.build();
        rightMap.keySet().stream().forEach(k -> l.putAll(k, rightMap.get(k)));
        return l;
    };

    Function<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>, ImmutableListMultimap<K, V>> finisher = ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::build;

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```

UPDATE - to reflect fge's suggestion and simplify the combiner

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMultimap<K, V>> toImmutableListMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {

    Supplier<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, V>> supplier = ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::new;

    BiConsumer<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, V>, T> accumulator = (b, t) -> b
            .put(keyMapper.apply(t), valueMapper.apply(t));

    BinaryOperator<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, V>> combiner = (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build());

    Function<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, V>, ImmutableMultimap<K, V>> finisher = ImmutableMultimap.Builder::build;

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```

Comment: Uhm, not sure why you do it this way; [you can `.putAll()` a `Multimap` into another](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#putAll(com.google.common.collect.Multimap)); as such your existing collector should work as is, by just replacing `ImmutableMap` by `ImmutableMultimap`

Comment: Wait so are you saying it should be cast down to an ImmutableMultiMap? I'm not quite sure what you mean otherwise...

Comment: I mean that your combiner can simply be `(l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build())` -- this method is defined by the `Multimap` interface, therefore by `ListMultimap` which inherits it

Comment: It looks like you're right, I didn't look at the inherited method from Multimap. It looks like it does accept an entire map. Good deal.

Comment: You can still improve upon that; after all, an `ImmutableMultimap` is still a `Multimap`, so you need not declare your third type parameter as `Immutable` and similarly, the finisher can be "downcast" to a `Multimap` for production too. After all, there are no methods on `ImmutableMultimap` which `Multimap` doesn't have; OK, well, maybe you need a `ListMultimap` if you need your .get()s to return Lists instead of Collections

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about all the above. I find it easier to keep immutable stuff casted as immutable wherever its called, just so its immutability is documented. With the List vs Collection thing, I have to think about that...